# RJ45 sleeve slips off after crimping

Tags: rj-45

I've had to crimp a few cables with an RJ45 connector to get my house wired up. I noticed on some old ones that I had crimped, the plastic sleeve has slipped out of the connector. The cable still seems to work but I'm trying to figure out how I could avoid that in the future. Is there some technique that I'm missing?

[image: Example picture]

Comment: You do want to be tight fisted with the amount of outer sheeth you remove. You also might additionally want to get boots which go between the cable and jack -like https://m.ebay.com/itm/RJ45-Connectors-and-Boots-Cat5e-Cat6-Network-LAN-Ethernet-Patch-Cable-Wholesale-/222464146901?ul_ref=https%3A%2F%2Frover.ebay.com%2Frover%2F1%2F711-53200-19255-0%2F1%3Ficep_ff3%3D2&pub=5574933636&toolid=10001&campid=5337590781&customid=&mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fitm%2FRJ45-Connectors-and-Boots-Cat5e-Cat6-Network-LAN-Ethernet-Patch-Cable-Wholesale-%2F222464146901&_mwBanner=1&_rdt=1&ul_noapp=true

Answer (score 6):

Your picture indicates that you cut the outer shield too far back. That is, the strands are too long, leaving nothing to grasp the shield.

As you note it works. But it is weaker overall, and you should start again, make sure the exposed wires are not too long and then crimp again.

Comment: It also helps to *slightly* shove/stretch the outer sheath into the jack just before and as you crimp.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answer, you should pull the exposed wires out to slide the sheath back, then pinch the sheath and wires in one hand to hold them securely in place while you prepare them with the other hand to be pushed in to the connector.

Then, while still pinching the sheath and wires slide the exposed wires firmly in to place in the connector then release the pinched sheath and push the sheath forward to secure it in the connector as well. Then crimp.

Pulling the wires out some and firmly pinching the cable will take up the slack and allow you to better push the wires then the sheath in to the connector.